# How to change the docusaurus browser tab text to match the current page

Tags: javascript, browser-tab, docusaurus

On a Docusaurus Site, it seems that any `page` will simply display the **site `title`** in the browser tab, but once you get down to the `doc` level, the browser tab *does* reflect the title of the page (`doc`) you are on.

Because the `title` of the `doc` is what gets displayed in the browser tab (and because the `title` of the site is what is displayed in the browser tab for all `pages`), I have been searching for places to set a "title" for the `pages`, but I either have not found the correct place to set the `title` or that is not the answer.

I have also tried setting the browser tab text in a more conventional way (like using `document.title`), but I am told that the `document` object cannot be found.

I feel like there has to be a place that says "anything that is of type `page` should display this text in the browser tab" (or just "the browser tab should display ___ text") but I've been unable to locate that code...

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Answer (score 2):

I found this merged PR: https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/704

The answer is to put:

```
*yourPageName*.title = "Your Desired Titile";
```

just above the `module.exports` at the end of the `page`.